# Deriving a recurrence equation and apply Master's Thrm to it

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, computer-science

So for a function such as:

```
function Hi(n)
if n > 1 then
for j ← 1 to n
    do print(”Hi”)
Hi(n/2)
Hi(n/2)
Hi(n/2)
```

It's very easy to eyeball this and get a recurrence of:

```
T(n) = 3(n/2) + n
```

And then applying Master's Theorem to get its Big Ɵ is also very straightforward.

But what confuses me is what do I do when there's some code after the recursive calls and the base case happens are n < (some number greater than 1), like this:

```
Function PrintZs (integer n)
    if n < 3
        print(“Z”)
    else
        PrintZs(n/3)
        PrintZs(n/3)
        PrintZs(n/3)
        for i ← 1 to 2n do print(“Z”)
```

Here 2 things are different: the base case has n < 3 rather than n < 1, and there

My thought is that the recursive function will be:

```
T(n) = 3T(n/3) + 2n + 1
```

I'm ignoring the fact that the base case happens at n < 3 rather than n < 1 because this only takes off 1 level of the recursive calls, which is an irrelevant amount. 2n is obviously there for the 2n prints, which will only happen when n >= 3.

Then when I apply master's theorem to this problem, I will treat the equation as:

```
 T(n) = 3T(n/3) + 2n
```

Since that 1 print call in the if statement is irrelevant to the 2n print calls that happen every call to the function (where n >= 3).

Is my thought process correct? If not, what needs to be changed?

Comment: The case $n<3$ adds only a constant amount of work to the calculation, so yes, you can essentially neglect that contribution for the asymptotics.

Comment: So is my final recurrence relation of  T(n) = 3T(n/3) + 2n right? This is the first time I've ever dealt with getting equations for recursive functions with code after the recursive calls, so I'm not very sure with my answer.

Comment: It will get you the right asymptotic. It is not exactly the same as your actual problem, but it is asymptotically equivalent to it. Pedantically speaking you should write $T(n) = 3 T(n/3) + f(n)$ and comment that $f(n) \in \Theta(n)$.

Comment: Would my actual problem be: T(n) = 3T(n/3) + 2n + 1, with the + 1 in it to account for the 1 print statement under if.

Comment: That's not exactly right, because it only comes up once per whole stack of recursive calls, whereas what you've written counts it $\log_3(n)$ times. If it's not clear, try actually performing the algorithm when $n=9$ to see what I mean.

Comment: I know what you mean; it'll happen every recursive call (~log3(x) times) rather than only happening at the bottom when I write it like that. My professor writes the recursive equation as:

    T(n) = a(T/b) + cn^d

where cn^d is the number of prints under if, so I just copied his format, so I just copied his format.

Comment: Just noticed that his format was for when the recursive calls were nested in the if statement, so I'm removing the + 1.